# MPMoviePlayerViewController is not playing video from url

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, mp4

I am trying to play a mp4 video on my web site.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/video.mp4"]];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500);
    moviePlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;


   moviePlayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType= MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [moviePlayer.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

    [moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
```

It is not playing the video and gives this error:

```
2013-12-08 22:31:00.497 UIWebViewVideoArge[684:60b] _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

Comment: does the video work when you load it directly through a web-browser?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068681/itemfailedtoplaytoend-error-when-playing-video-in-mpmovieplayercontroller

Answer (score 2):

Url in your code:`http://mywebsite.com/video.mp4` - not valid. With this url player produces an error like in your question. But if you try use another url (for example: `http://nordenmovil.com/urrea/InstalaciondelavaboURREAbaja.mp4` - use it for test) your player will work without errors, but not correct. For correct work you must change your code:

add to your `.h` file in `@interface` section property (do not forget add `@import MediaPlayer`):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer;
```

and change your code like below:

```
  _moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nordenmovil.com/urrea/InstalaciondelavaboURREAbaja.mp4"]];
  _moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500);
  _moviePlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;


  _moviePlayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType= MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
  [_moviePlayer.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];

  [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];

  [_moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
```

As alternative you can use `UIWebView` for play video:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nordenmovil.com/urrea/InstalaciondelavaboURREAbaja.mp4"];
NSURLRequest* requestUrl = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:fileURL];
UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView loadRequest:requestUrl];
```

If you will use `UIWebView` for play video - try use your url and you will see what your link is wrong.

Comment: can i play youtbue url ?

Comment: @MANCHIKANTIKRISHNAKISHORE No, 'MPMoviePlayer' not play video from direct link (perhaps unsupported video format). But if you use 'UIWebView' you can use link like 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyP58SorNUI' for display web page with embedded player (direct link not work too).